# como obtener el id de un objeto para pasarlo al backend al actualizar un registro en angular

Tags: nodejs, angular, api

tengo un frontend en el que actualizo un registro por this.route.params.subscribe... obtengo los datos del libro para mostrarlo en el formulario pero a la hora de insertar una imagen usando la libreria angular file uploader no consigo obtener el id del libro por que la libreria utiliza:

```
afuConfig: AngularFileUploaderConfig = {
  multiple: false,
  formatsAllowed: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif',
  uploadAPI:{
    url: 'http://localhost:3999/admin/' + 'upload-avatar', 
    method: 'PUT',    
  },
  theme: 'attachPin',
  hideProgressBar: false,
  hideResetBtn: true,
  hideSelectBtn: false,
};
```

esta es la url del componente donde tengo el formulario con el registro a actualizar

```
http://localhost:4200/updatebook/5f45bc963ef14d1ad547e5c6 // 5f45 es el id del libro
```

en afuConfig no se como meterle el id del libro

cargo en el formulario el libro con

```
getBook()
{
  this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{
    let id = params['id'];
    this.bookservice.getBook(id).subscribe(
      response =>
      {
        if(!response.book)
        {
          this.router.navigate(['/pruebabook']);
        }
        else
        {
          this.book = response.book;
           this.forma.controls['id'].setValue(response.book._id); 
           this.forma.controls['title'].setValue(response.book.title);
           this.forma.controls['description'].setValue(response.book.description);
           this.forma.controls['author'].setValue(response.book.author);
           this.forma.controls['stock'].setValue(response.book.stock);
           this.forma.controls['price'].setValue(response.book.price);
          console.log(this.book);
        }
      }
    )
  });
}
```

el backend está hecho en nodejs

```
} else {
            //Sacar el id del libro
            var params = req.params.id;// no recoje nada
            console.log(params);
            var bookId = req.params.bookId; //undefined
            console.log('bookid', bookId);
            // Buscar y actualizar documento bd
            Book.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: bookId }, { image: file_name }, { new: true }, (err, bookUpdated) => {

                if (err || !bookUpdated) {
                    // Devolver respuesta
                    return res.status(500).send({
                        status: 'error',
                        message: 'Error al guardar la imagen'
                    });
                }

                // Devolver respuesta
                return res.status(200).send({
                    status: 'success',
                    // image: book.image,
                    user: bookUpdated
                });

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de la librería que mencionas es posible añadir un parámetro a tu petición.

[angular-file-uploader](https://github.com/kzrfaisal/angular-file-uploader)

```
  params: {
    'bookId': this.book._id
  },
```

Por lo que tu código debería de ser algo como en el siguiente ejemplo, y posterior el parámetro podrás obtenerlo en tu Backend, desde el get.

[http url-params.](https://angular.io/guide/http#url-params)

```
  public afuConfig = any; //Inicializar la variable vacia


  public setConfig() {
    //Asignar la variable cuando ya se tenga el valor a enviar
    this.afuConfig = AngularFileUploaderConfig = {
      multiple: false,
      formatsAllowed: '.jpg, .jpeg, .png, .gif',
      uploadAPI: {
        url: 'http://localhost:3999/admin/' + 'upload-avatar',
        method: 'PUT',
        params: {
          'bookId': this.book._id
        },
      },
      theme: 'attachPin',
      hideProgressBar: false,
      hideResetBtn: true,
      hideSelectBtn: false,
    };
  }

  getBook() {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let id = params['id'];
      this.bookservice.getBook(id).subscribe(
        response => {
          if (!response.book) {
            this.router.navigate(['/pruebabook']);
          }
          else {
            this.book = response.book;
            this.forma.controls['id'].setValue(response.book._id);
            this.forma.controls['title'].setValue(response.book.title);
            this.forma.controls['description'].setValue(response.book.description);
            this.forma.controls['author'].setValue(response.book.author);
            this.forma.controls['stock'].setValue(response.book.stock);
            this.forma.controls['price'].setValue(response.book.price);
            this.setConfig();// Lo puse aqui, pero desde que obtienes el valor puedes asignarlo, y no tomarlo de this.bool
            console.log(this.book);
          }
        }
      )
    });
  }
```

Comment: no puedo poner ninguna variable en params me da este error core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined    tiene que ser un string

Comment: checa que tu objeto book tenga valores al asignarlo

Comment: Ahí el problema que te marca es que this.book esta indefinido

Comment: no sé como asignarle al objeto libro el id para en la funcion del backend actualizar ese libro